# Tkinter textbox does not look the same as terminal print

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tkinter, customtkinter

My TKinter textbox formats weirdly and does not look like the command text. I have a
pandas db and it inserts it weirdly. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
        table = PrettyTable()

        # Set the column names
        table.field_names = df.columns.tolist()
        for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
            table.add_row(row)
        textbox_string = str(table)
        #df.columns = ['owner ', 'project ', 'branch ', 'updated ', 'insertions ', 'deletions ']
        #df.style.set_properties(subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, :], **{'width': '50px'})
       
        #textbox_string = df.to_string(index=True, justify='center')
        print(textbox_string)
        root.textbox.configure(font=("Roboto", 14))
        root.textbox.insert("0.0",textbox_string)
```

Console text
[the console text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RCgU.png)
Here's how the GUI shows it
[TKinter textbox text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ4DX.png)

I'm a bit new on this. Does anyone have any idea?

I've tried multiple things, but none have worked

Comment: It is because you do not use a fixed width font (or monospaced font) for the text box widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```py
root.textbox.configure(font=("Roboto", 14))
```

with this

```py
root.textbox.configure(font='TkFixedFont')
```

This will use the system monospace font. If you prefer to explicitly set it to *Roboto*, use *Roboto Mono* instead, like this:

```py
root.textbox.configure(font=("Roboto Mono", 14))
```

Comment: Thank you Friedrich and @acw1668 ! Awesome help <3

Comment: Glad it worked. Credits go to @acw1668 for spotting it so quickly.